# I want to make a header a link with css. Not Duplicate, the other one is 2008

Tags: html, css

I want to make a `<h1 class="header"> Some Title </h1>` a link with only css, without adding the `href="google.com"` in the html part.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: You can add the *look* of a link, you can't add the behaviour of one using CSS.

Comment: You can't do that with CSS, as far as I know. You could use Javascript and the onclick event though.

Comment: The real question is why are you trying to do this?

Comment: What is the goal? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @jmargolisvt Because I only have access to the css part for modifications. I am using nothing else than (mywebsite.com/wp-admin) part of the wordpress thing.

Comment: Assuming you have admin access, you can edit all the files you need from the wp-admin area.  Learn to make a child theme and go from there.

Comment: Good idea @jmargolisvt I'll leave this question open until css4 comes to the rescue.

Answer (score 3):

The link adress MUST be in the HTML, you can't put it into CSS. Wrap your `<h1>` tag with an `<a>` tag:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com"><h1 class="header"> Some Title </h1></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way create a link in your html with CSS only. What you can do is to use JavaScript to convert your h1 tags or tag into a link.